# Using ESS (Emacs Speaks Statistics) with nix

Tags: emacs, ess, nix

I'd like to use ESS with the nix version of R and the packages I need.

Here's what I can do via the shell

```
nix-shell shell.nix -I nixpkgs=/Users/dom/nixpkgs --run R
```

`shell.nix` ensures I have R and the R packages available without have to do `install.packages`. E.g. I get the version of ggplot2 in nix:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0 (64-bit)

> installed.packages()["ggplot2","LibPath"]
installed.packages()["ggplot2","LibPath"]
[1] "/nix/store/4nm5rs5d0ywpw7ksd0hblminim4kvnr0-r-ggplot2-2.2.1/library"
```

ESS has the variables

- `inferior-R-program-name`
- `inferior-R-args`

Here's what I did for python but note that python mode has `python-shell-process-environment` which allows me to set the NIX environment variables.

```
 '(python-shell-interpreter "/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/nix-shell")
 '(python-shell-interpreter-args
   "-p \"callPackage /Users/dom/Dropbox/Tidy/mrp/dl.nix {}\" -I nixpkgs=/Users/dom/nixpkgs --run python")
 '(python-shell-process-environment
   (quote
    ("NIX_PROFILES=/nix/var/nix/profiles/default /Users/dom/.nix-profile" "NIX_REMOTE=daemon" "NIX_PATH=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels" "NIX_SSL_CERT_FILE=/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt" "NIX_USER_PROFILE_DIR=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/dom"))))
```

Repeating my original question, is there anything similar I can do to persuade ESS to use the nix version of R (and associated packages)?

Comment: You might want to use [nix-buffer](https://github.com/shlevy/nix-buffer/blob/b922497ea0af39fdf1a7e856d0cd2ce81d98d76f/nix-buffer.el#L192) to run Elisp built by Nix. You can use it to put your R environment in `exec-path`

Comment: Thank you but I am not really sure how to use this. I put this in the directory containing my .R file: https://gist.github.com/idontgetoutmuch/7a3e4b302dc0bd499a4dab0ee1a204ed and then executed `nix-buffer` but got `nix-buffer--nix-build: Searching for program: No such file or directory, nix-build`. Before I use nix in a shell I execute `source /nix/var/nix/profiles/default/etc/profile.d/nix-daemon.sh` so maybe there is something I need to do before executing `nix-buffer`?

Comment: I have got slightly further by putting `(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
` in my `.emacs` but now I get `nix-build for nix-buffer for mrp_script.R<Tidy> exited abnormally with code 1 with error output: 
error: Nix database directory ‘/nix/var/nix/db’ is not writable: Permission denied` which I am pretty sure is caused by not having the `NIX` environment variables set.

Comment: By setting the NIX environment variables, `nix-buffer` runs to completion and if I then do `getenv PATH` I can see that it includes `/nix/store/cz79yxnzsi2262i972pbfgvd93lf9y5k-R-3.4.3/bin:...` But if I try to invoke R via ESS I get `Searching for program: No such file or directory, R` and if I do M-x shell and `echo $PATH` then the prefix which contains the location of R in nix is no longer prefixed to the path.

Comment: Sometimes my PATH is `/Users/dom/.nix-profile/bin:/Users/dom/.nix-profile/sbin:/Users/dom/.nix-profile/lib/kde4/libexec:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/sbin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/lib/kde4/libexec:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin` and sometimes it is `/nix/store/cz79yxnzsi2262i972pbfgvd93lf9y5k-R-3.4.3/bin:/nix/store/cz79yxnzsi2262i972pbfgvd93lf9y5k-R-3.4.3/bin:/nix/store/cz79yxnzsi2262i972pbfgvd93lf9y5k-R-3.4.3/bin:/nix/store/cz79yxnzsi2262i972pbfgvd93lf9y5k-R-3.4.3/bin:/Users/dom/.nix-profile/bin:...`

Comment: Note that `nix-buffer` prefixes the path each time it is invoked but these prefixes disappear if I do M-x shell

Comment: Open a regular shell buffer with `M-x shell`, run your `nix-shell` command there, then do `M-x ess-remote` and select `R`. ESS will then recognize this buffer as its interactive R session.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks very much - I will make it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a regular shell buffer with M-x shell, run your nix-shell command there, then do M-x ess-remote and select R. ESS will then recognize this buffer as its interactive R session.

NB You need to run R before M-x ess-remote.